# Copied queue changes Queue's head pointer points to null after printing temp Queue

Tags: c++, list, queue, hashtable

After the end of dumpStack, the call to printTable prints the hashTable with the queue in each index perfectly fine. When I try to individually print it afterwards, head->next points to null (the head points to a dummy node). How can I print the temp queue without changing the main queue's pointers? I'm not allowed to use vectors.

```
void dumpStack(listNode *top, int currentDigit, int currentTable) {
    while (isEmpty() == 0) {
        listNode *temp = pop();
        int digit = getDigit(temp, currentDigit);
        int hashIndex = digit;
        addTail(hashTable[currentTable][hashIndex], temp);
        cout << "Added " << temp->data << " to hashTable[" << currentTable << "][" << hashIndex << "]" << endl;
        cout << hashTable[currentTable][hashIndex]->head->next->data << endl;
    }
    cout << "DONE DUMPSTACK" << endl;
    printTable(hashTable[currentTable]);
    cout << hashTable[currentTable][9]->head->next->data << endl;
}

void printTable(linkedListQueue **ht) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        linkedListQueue *temp = ht[i];
        if (isEmpty(temp) == 0) {
            cout << "Table [" << currentTable << "][" << i << "]:";
            while (temp->head->next != nullptr) {
                cout << " " << temp->head->next->data;
                if (temp->head->next->next != nullptr)
                    cout << ",";
                temp->head->next = temp->head->next->next;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

All parts of my code are correct and it does not have any runtime errors.

Comment: When In see a pop function in a while not empty loop, I expect an empty container at the end. Can we have a [mcve]? Sidenote: Lot of unexpected pointer use here. Example: what is `top` for?

Comment: What dumpStack does is it takes a stack and puts into a queue. After dumping the whole stack to a queue, it prints the each queue in the hashTable (total of 10 queues). So if I had numbers 19 and 9 in a queue, it would go in hashTable[9]. I use a temp pointer to reference the queue in hashTable[9] and use the temp variable to iterate. Not sure why the main queue would change as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was I changed listLinkedQueue *temp into listNode *temp and let temp equal to head->next since head represents a dummy node in my code. This way I never change the original sequence of the queue when I iterate through it.

```
void printTable(linkedListQueue **ht) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        listNode *temp = ht[i]->head->next;
        if (temp != nullptr) {
            cout << "Table [" << currentTable << "][" << i << "]:";
            while (temp != nullptr) {
                cout << " " << temp->data;
                if (temp->next != nullptr)
                    cout << ",";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```